# How to divide a data frame column by a value in another column, repeating for multiple products in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have two data frames, `A` and `B`. Both data frames have values for three different products.

Here's A:

```
    Product Q1
1 Product X  4
2 Product Y  7
3 Product Z  8
```

And here's B:

```
    Product Q1
1 Product X 41
2 Product Y 72
3 Product Z 89
```

I would like to run a calculation on these data frames by doing the following:

- Divide *Product X's Q1 value in A* by *Product X's Q1 value in B*. Then divide *Product X's Q1 value in A* by *Product Y's Q1 value in B*. Then on to Z. (So *Product X's Q1 value in A* is a constant and its being divided by each product's Q1 value in B.)
- Then the next column would be the same, but for *Product Y's Q1 value in Q*.
- Finally, the same thing for Z.

Ideally I would end up with a dataframe like this:

```
    Product ProductXdiv ProductYdiv ProductZdiv
1 Product X  0.09756098  0.17073171  0.19512195
2 Product Y  0.05555556  0.09722222  0.11111111
3 Product Z  0.04494382  0.07865168  0.08988764
```

Is there a package that can help calculate this in a fairly straightforward way? Or would it require a custom function? Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: `a <- c(4, 7, 8) ;
b <- c(41, 72, 89) ;
outer(a, b, "/")` or `a %*% t(1 / b)` (possibly transposed again)

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using `sapply` to iterate over `A[,2]` and `B[,2]`. You can use `setNames` to rename the columns as you see fit.

```
cbind(A, sapply(A[,2], function(d) sapply(B[,2], function(x) d/x)))

   Product Q1          1          2          3
1 ProductX  4 0.09756098 0.17073171 0.19512195
2 ProductY  7 0.05555556 0.09722222 0.11111111
3 ProductZ  8 0.04494382 0.07865169 0.08988764
```

Comment: Wow, that is way simpler than I thought it would be. Thank you.

Another quick question: Assume I have a Q2 column in both A and B... How do I just apply the function you suggest to Q1 and not subsequent columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyr solution.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

A<-data.frame(Product<-c("X","Y","Z"),Q1<-c(4,7,8))
B<-data.frame(Product<-c("X","Y","Z"),Q1<-c(41,72,89))

x<-merge.data.frame(A,B,by=NULL)
names(x)<-c("ProductA","Q1A","ProductB","Q1B")

x%<>%mutate(div=Q1A/Q1B)%>%
    select(-Q1A,-Q1B)%>%
    spread(ProductB,div)
```